# How to publish custom topic from command line

Tags: ros-melodic, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I have a ROS Node that uses custom messages:

```
//robo_io.msg
bool out_0
bool out_1
int64 var1
```

I publish them from my node in C++ in this way:

```
var_pub = n.advertise<robo_explorer::robo_io>("/robo_explorer/io_status, 1000);
```

and it works very well!

The problem is that I would like to send some messages by using the terminal, but I'm having problems with the syntax to use.

I tried with:

```
rostopic pub /robo_explorer/io_status std_msgs/Bool "out_1: true"
```

but it says that there is no field name `out_1`.

Can you help, me?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365913/how-to-publish-custom-topic-from-command-line/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2020-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To publish on a topic you need to use the topic type of that topic (just like you are doing in C++).

`rostopic pub /robo_explorer/io_status robo_explorer/robo_io "{ out_1: true }"`

Assuming that's the namespace and name of your custom message and you've sourced your workspace in the current shell (so that rostopic can find the custom message definition).

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2020-11-19**:
Additionally, you should be able to use tab completion after typing `rostopic pub /robo_explorer/io_status`, and it will automagically fill in both the message type and then the correct syntax to specify the values.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-12-02**:
Thank you!!! It works fine!